# FTP retrieve user home directory from an admin connection

Tags: ftp, sftp, user-permissions

I'm implementing a cleanup of old files on SFTP server. I have a user named `admin` who has full access rights on the FTP.

I would like to know if it's possible to retrieve the **home directory** for another "classic" user when being connected as an admin.

To illustrate imagine 2 users

- `admin` with full access on the FTP
- `bob` is a simple user that has his own directory on the FTP

I want to know as an `admin`  what is the **home directory** of `bob`

If you need more context let me know.

Any helps would be greatly appreciated